# Default empty case for varargs

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, variadic-functions

Say you wish to use pattern matching when calling a method with varargs like so:

```
def foo(bar: Int*) = ???

val x = false
foo(x match {
  case true => 1
  case _ =>
})
```

Running the above code results in type mismatch error, since `foo` requires an argument of type `Int` but found `Unit` instead in the default case. Removing the default case, on the other hand, results in a warning that the match may not be exhaustive, and rightfully so.

My question is, how do I supply an *empty* default case for the match (which would result in calling `foo()` without any arguments)?

Comment: If you're only ever passing a single `Int`, why use varargs?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the example given is a MWE, the actual use case is more complicated

Comment: If this MWE isn't your real problem, we might not be able to provide the best solution as we're only seeing a "close relative" of the actual problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov without going into too much detail, I have a method which accepts varargs. I need to call this method in three different ways: without any arguments, with one argument, or with several arguments. To decide which argument(s) to call my method with, I pattern match on a variable that has over 20 different possible values, but I'm only really interested in a couple of those. In every other case I wish to call my method without any arguments. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 3):

You could capture the match result in a sequence and represent the lack of arguments as an empty one. Then just splat the result into the parameter:

```
val x = true
foo((x match {
  case true => Seq(1)
  case _ => Seq.empty
}):_*)
```

Comment: It may be more readable as `val args = x match ...; foo(args: _*)`.

Comment: Certainly is. If its as complex as OPs comment suggests (20+ values) it may even warrant its own method to keep things clean. But obviously we're not seeing the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use an `Option[Int]` instead of an `Int`:

```
def foo(bar: Option[Int]*) = ???

val x = false
foo(x match {
  case true => Some(1)
  case _ => None
})
```

I think an `if-else` expression would be less verbose here:

```
foo(if (x) Some(1) else None)
```

I'd argue though that if you're matching over a single `Boolean` there's no point in passing varargs at all.